# AngularJS with spring security - general flow of authentication

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-security

Can anyone how look general flow of authentication in spring security, where frontend (so also login panel) is provieded by angularJS and node server ?
How should be these modules connected ?

Comment: what is the role of spring security here?

Comment: Securiting REST API serve by spring

Comment: have you checked this? https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/

Comment: Thanks. However, I ask you for simple model of flow. It helps me much :)

Comment: The flow of authentication is not related to a specific server, you need some sort of securing your api, like checking if the current request has a token issued by your server and if everything is ok let say that the user is authenticated, in your client side you call an api provided by server and receive a token, store that token on user machine and in every request send that token along with your request, and for securing your routes there are a lot of methods like using `data` for `ui-router` states ...

Comment: Ok, thanks. Token sent by client must be generated by for this one session (created during logining). Yeah  ?

Answer (score 0):

I have been involved in three angularjs apps and in each of them we handled the whole user authentication/authorization in following way:

we defined a `currentUser` service which holds the information of current user of our application, things like user roles, email, name and ..., and this service have a very important method named `isLoggedIn` which based on this service values determine if user is logged in or not.

on the server side we have some sort of api which returns a token to a user after user have provided valid credentials, we post username/pass to the api and in response we receive a token and store it in a cookie or local sotrage. there are various ways of returning a token on would be using JWT(Json Web Token).

Tokens are sent in each request by help of `$http interceptors`, token may expire after 30 minutes which result in an unauthorized response from server.

for JWT refer to [this](http://www.svlada.com/jwt-token-authentication-with-spring-boot/#jwt-authentication) link.
for client side authentication/authorization you can take a look at ng-book or [this](https://medium.com/opinionated-angularjs/techniques-for-authentication-in-angularjs-applications-7bbf0346acec) link.